# Can't get mail MessageID or UID when messageRomoved listener fired

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have set a MessageCountListener to a IMAP folder. When messages removed/Added the listeners are getting fired properly. In order to update the changes to my local client, I need messageID or UID. But inside the messageRemoved() method, when I try to get MessageID or UID, it throws a MessageRemoved exception.

Is there a way to get messageID or UID inside messageRemoved() handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the message number for an expunged message.

If you've previously fetched the UID for a message, you should be able to get the UID of the message after it has been expunged.

You can't get the Message-ID or other headers for an expunged message.

Comment: @Bill, so inside a MessageCountListener.messagesRemoved is possible to retrieve message UID simply calling ((UIDFolder)folder).getUID(message);

So there is no need to store and mantain a map with messages number as key and UID as values? In fact it is enough reading UID and using it to find a previously cached (inside consumer application) messag, am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: If JavaMail has previously seen the UID for the message, it will cache it and you can access it as you describe after the message is expunged.